# Xcode using @1x for iphone 5

Tags: ios, iphone, image

I am trying to work out all of these images and sizes.

I have a file called logo.png - and I have the three required ones logo@3x.png - logo@2x.png - logo.png

When I try and use this image, and run it on iPhone 5S I can see by printing the image size, that the image size is {334, 44}, which is the size of the logo.png

How do I fix this?

I have added all images to a asset, and the image name is just "logo" as the asset is called.

Comment: The reported size in in points, not pixels. All should have the same point size. That's expected.

Comment: Alright, what mode should I set the image to? Aspect Fit? Or?

Comment: What ever mode fits your needs. Maybe if you updated your question to be  clear about what issue you having or what problem you are trying to solve, it would be easier to give more concrete answers.

Comment: Okay, I have this logo image at 1001x133 at @ 3x - and its 668x88 at @ 2x, and as far as I know it uses @ 2x for iPhone 5, and the iphone width is 640px, I dont quite understand the image size then? If the @ 2x is larger than the actual screen size?? @maddy